# Can't find tags from attributes with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When working on a web scraping project using Beautiful Soup I tried to find all "tr" elements with custom attributes but it returned nothing using `.find_all('tr', attrs={'role': 'row'})`. When I just find all 'tr' I get too many results. On top of this when I tried just finding all 'tr' that had a class using both `.find_all('tr', attrs={'class': 'even'})` and `.find_all('tr', class_='even')` I also got zero results. After checking the BS4 documentation I feel like the code I have should work but I am clearly wrong about that, so how can I find tags with classes and custom attributes?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

table_url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'

pop_page = requests.get(table_url).content
table_text = BeautifulSoup(pop_page, 'html.parser')

table_rows = table_text.find_all('tr', attrs={"role": "row"})
```

Note: I copy-pasted all of the classes and attribute names so I am very confident that a typo is not the issue.

Comment: check your `pop_page` and make sure it contains what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `role="row"` from attributes (this is added by JavaScript, so beautifulsoup doesn't see it):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table_url = "https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/"

pop_page = requests.get(table_url).content
table_text = BeautifulSoup(pop_page, "html.parser")

table_rows = table_text.find_all("tr")
print(len(table_rows))
```

Prints:

```
235
```

Answer (score 0):

I just used the **tbody**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

table_url = 'https://www.worldometers.info/world-population/population-by-country/'
pop_page = requests.get(table_url).content
table_text = BeautifulSoup(pop_page, 'html.parser')

table_rows = table_text.find_all('tbody')
for row in table_rows:
    countries = row.find_all_next('tr')
    print('total_count:', len(countries))
    for country in countries:
        text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', country.text).strip()
        result = text.split(' ')
        result_list = [item for item in result[1:] if item != '%']
        print(result_list)
```

[image]